# Having trouble writing remotely to Cassandra server from node.js

Tags: node.js, cassandra

Environment: OS: Debian, Cassandra: 3.10, Node.js 7.5.0,cassandra-driver: 3.2.0

Error:
(node:7484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, 192.168.10.151:9042: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.10.151:9042. See innerErrors.(node:7484) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Nodejs Code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
var async = require('async');
var client = new cassandra.Client({contactPoints: ['192.168.10.151'], keyspace: 'users'});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var query = 'INSERT INTO userAuth(email,password) VALUES(req.body.email,req.body.password)';
    client.execute(query);
    });

module.exports = router;
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: are you sure you are running cassandra process on `192.168.10.151` `9042`?

Comment: Yes, i can connect to it via ssh and query using cql. According to Cassandra documentation the default client port is 9042.

Answer (score 1):

your insert statement also doesn't seem to be valid. Can you please try with

`'INSERT INTO userAuth(email,password) VALUES(?,?)'`

and then

`execute(query, [req.body.email, req.body.email]);`

plus I think ti might be a good idea to add function for query result handling

```
function(n, row) {
    console.log('everything is o.k.');
},
function (err) {
   console.log('something went wrong', err);
}
```

Also the error seems to be very similar to this one, so try to update the broadcast address in the cassandra.yaml file to 192.168.10.151

[dse-driver connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519381/dse-driver-connection-refused)

Comment: I set cassandra.yaml broadcast_address to 192.168.10.151, rpc_address and listen_address by I still can't connect to it. I can't cqlsh into that ip. It only works if I set it to localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't have cassandra user?

If you do have one, connect to cassandra this way:

```
const authProvider = new cassandra.auth.PlainTextAuthProvider('user', 'pass');

const client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['192.168.10.151'], keyspace: 'users', authProvider: authProvider});
```